# Random Forest in R - Applying to testing/validation set

Tags: r, random-forest

I am a beginner to using Random Forest. I am trying to train a random forest model then apply it to a testing dataset but am having problems getting two datasets that are the same length. I have trained a good model but need to see how it performs on my test data. Please see my code below. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
#Import Data
url <- "http://groupware.les.inf.puc-rio.br/static/WLE/WearableComputing_weight_lifting_exercises_biceps_curl_variations.csv"
df <- read.csv(url, header = TRUE, na.strings=c("NA","#DIV/0!",""))

#Remove columns containing ALL NA values
df <- df[,colSums(is.na(df)) == 0]

#Remove all irrelevant columns that you will not need as predictors 
df <- subset(df, select = -c(1:7))

#Create training and testing datasets
library(caret)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = df$classe,
                               p=0.7, list = FALSE)
training <- df[inTrain,]
testing <- df[-inTrain,]

set.seed(2020)

rfmodel <- randomForest(classe ~ ., data = training, method="rf", ntree=100, importance = TRUE)
print(rfmodel) #Error rate of 0.17% = good!

#validating that this method works on training set
prediction_train <- predict(rfmodel, data = training, type = "class")
table(prediction_train, training$classe)

#Cannot figure out what is going wrong here
prediction_test <- predict(rfmodel, data = testing)
length(prediction_test) #27472
length(testing$classe) #11770
table(prediction_test, testing$classe) #ERROR (see below)
#Error in table(prediction_test, testing$classe) : all arguments must have the same length
```

Packages I am using:

> version$version.string
>   [1] "R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)"
>   packageVersion("caret", lib.loc = NULL)
>   [1] ‘6.0.85’
>   packageVersion("rattle", lib.loc = NULL)
>   [1] ‘5.3.0’
>   packageVersion("randomForest", lib.loc = NULL)
>   [1] ‘4.6.14’
>   packageVersion("randomForestExplainer", lib.loc = NULL)
>   [1] ‘0.10.0’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `data =` when doing the testing. Cheers.

```
rfmodel <- randomForest(training$classe ~ ., data = training[,-51], method="rf", ntree=100, importance = TRUE)
prediction_test <- predict(rfmodel, testing[,-51])
table(prediction_test, testing$classe) 

prediction_test    A    B    C    D    E
              A 3346    3    0    0    0
              B    1 2274    4    0    0
              C    0    0 2049   15    0
              D    0    0    0 1913    0
              E    0    0    0    1 2164
```

Comment: Do you know an easy way to get the error rate on the prediction_test?

Comment: For classification problems, ```caret``` has a ```confusionMatrix``` function, please check.  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/confusionMatrix. There you can obtain many error estimators. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `newdata =` within `predict` function for both training and testing data like

```
#validation using training data
prediction_train <- predict(rfmodel, newdata = training, type = "class")
table(prediction_train, training$classe)

prediction_train    A    B    C    D    E
           A 7812    0    0    0    0
           B    0 5316    0    0    0
           C    0    0 4791    0    0
           D    0    0    0 4503    0
           E    0    0    0    0 5050

#validation using testing data
prediction_test <- predict(rfmodel, newdata = testing, type = "class")
length(prediction_test) 
length(testing$classe)
table(prediction_test, testing$classe)

prediction_test    A    B    C    D    E
              A 3346    7    0    0    0
              B    1 2269    1    0    0
              C    0    1 2052    4    0
              D    0    0    0 1924    1
              E    0    0    0    1 2163
```

Answer (score 0):

using sklearn I was able to be 96% accuracy.  I used 400 trees and a max depth of 32. The deep tree seems to be preferred allowing for greater accuracy.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV


df=pd.read_csv('weight_training.csv')

#https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/230066_902d438b84794c6cb5585496ebc82119.html
LABELS= ['raw_timestamp_part_1', 
'yaw_belt',
'num_window',
'roll_belt',
'magnet_dumbbell_z',
'pitch_belt', 
'magnet_dumbbell_y', 
'accel_dumbbell_y', 
'pitch_forearm', 
'roll_arm', 
'roll_dumbbell', 
'accel_dumbbell_z']
 encoder=LabelEncoder()
 X=df[LABELS]
 y=encoder.fit_transform(df['classe'])

 corr=df[LABELS].corr()
 plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
 sns.heatmap(corr,annot=True)
 plt.show()

 X_train,X_test,y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

 pipeline= Pipeline([
 ('scaler',StandardScaler()),
 ('pca', PCA()),
  ('clf',RandomForestClassifier(
      n_estimators=400, 
      max_depth=32,
      min_samples_leaf=2, 
      max_features=2, 
      random_state=42))
 ])
  pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)

 y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)
 cm = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)

 class_names=[1,2]
 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 tick_marks = np.arange(len(class_names))
 plt.xticks(tick_marks, class_names)
 plt.yticks(tick_marks, class_names)
 sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(cm), annot=True, cmap="coolwarm" ,fmt='g')
 ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
 plt.tight_layout()
 plt.title('Confusion matrix', y=1.1)
 plt.ylabel('Actual label')
 plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

 print("Accuracy Score",accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred));
```

output:

```
 Accuracy Score 0.96


 parameter_grid={'n_estimators':[1,2,100,400,450],'max_depth':[2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'min_samples_leaf':[1,2,4,6,8,10],'max_features':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}

number_models=8
random_RandomForest_class=RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator=pipeline['clf'],
    param_distributions=parameter_grid,
    n_iter=number_models,
    scoring='accuracy',
    n_jobs=2,
    cv=4,
    refit=True,
    return_train_score=True)

 random_RandomForest_class.fit(X_train,y_train)
 predictions=random_RandomForest_class.predict(X)

 print("Best params",random_RandomForest_class.best_params_)
 print("Best score",random_RandomForest_class.best_score_)
```